# fuse bad mount point

Tags: directory, fuse, mount-point

I am trying to mount a connection to map a folder from a cluster (running Ubuntu 16.04) to my local machine (Mac Book Pro). Therefore I am typing the following:

`sshfs username@host:/home/username/path_to_mount /Users/local_user/Desktop/existing_dir`

I get the following error:

`fuse: bad mount point '/Users/local_user/Desktop/existing_dir': No such file or directory`

That sounds really weird to me because the directory exists, I am sure of that. Any clue on why this happens and what might be a possible solution?

Maybe is just a stupid question, but I am no getting to any point!
Thanks for your help in advance!

Best,

Kim

Comment: 2.3 years and still I am getting same error. No real help yet found?

Answer (score 1):

After trying all the things which I found on the Internet regarding the issue I finally get to the point where I realized that I really missing a folder in the path to my mount point.

So to everyone struggling with this one: recheck!

Answer (score 1):

Here's my experience with this error - what I believe to be the cause and how I was able to get around it.

I came across this error after initially calling `sudo sshfs ..` with an incorrect user name and ultimately having to `ctrl-c` to break since the login attempt kept failing (obviously).  After some head scratching I checked `ls -l \mnt\xxx` and the attributes for xxx showed `d?????`.  To fix the problem I unmounted the directory and the repeated the `sshfs` with the correct parameters and everything worked as expected.